# Deserialize Xml error<xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I get this error when deserialize a Xml response from server:

> There is an error in XML document (2, 2). 
> was not expected.

This is my response xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RK7QueryResult ServerVersion="7.6.5.515" XmlVersion="248" NetName="RK7_TEST" Status="Ok" CMD="GetRefList" ErrorText="" DateTime="2022-08-11T09:44:22" WorkTime="156" Processed="1" ArrivalDateTime="2022-08-11T09:44:22">
    <RK7RefList Count="154">
        <RK7Reference RefName="ALIASES" Count="25" DataVersion="1681"/>
        <RK7Reference RefName="ALIASLANGUAGES" Count="29" DataVersion="2117"/>
    </RK7RefList>
</RK7QueryResult>
```

My Object:

```
[XmlRoot("RK7QueryResult")]
    public class ReferenceResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("ServerVersion")]
        public string ServerVersion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("XmlVersion")]
        public int XmlVersion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("NetName")]
        public string NetName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CMD")]
        public string CMD { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ErrorText")]
        public string ErrorText { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DateTime")]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("WorkTime")]
        public int WorkTime { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Processed")]
        public int Processed { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ArrivalDateTime")]
        public DateTime ArrivalDateTime { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("RK7RefList")]
        public List<Reference> RK7RefList { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("RK7Reference")]
    public class Reference
    {
        [XmlElement("RefName")]
        public string RefName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DataVersion")]
        public int DataVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

And my deserialization:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response.Data))
                {
                    var result = (ReferenceResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
```

I have searched many solution in here and tried but it isn't work for me, Did my object was worng or something else? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hi there, I had read this post before and tried add namespace but not work for me too.

Comment: You're using `[XmlElement]` on those properties when you should be using `[XmlAttribute]`.

Comment: @Dai I tried it before, it not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the serializer with "string" instead of the type you want to deserialize

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReferenceResponse));
```

and you should use [XmlAttribute] in your class for attributes.

This should work:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<RK7QueryResult ServerVersion=""7.6.5.515"" XmlVersion=""248"" NetName=""RK7_TEST"" Status=""Ok"" CMD=""GetRefList"" ErrorText="""" DateTime=""2022-08-11T09:44:22"" WorkTime=""156"" Processed=""1"" ArrivalDateTime=""2022-08-11T09:44:22"">
    <RK7RefList Count=""154"">
        <RK7Reference RefName=""ALIASES"" Count=""25"" DataVersion=""1681""/>
        <RK7Reference RefName=""ALIASLANGUAGES"" Count=""29"" DataVersion=""2117""/>
    </RK7RefList>
</RK7QueryResult>";
            
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReferenceResponse));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var result = (ReferenceResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ServerVersion);
            Console.WriteLine(result.RK7RefList[0].RefName);            
        }           
    }
}

[XmlRoot("RK7QueryResult")]
public class ReferenceResponse
{
    [XmlAttribute("ServerVersion")]
    public string ServerVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("XmlVersion")]
    public int XmlVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("NetName")]
    public string NetName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("CMD")]
    public string CMD { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ErrorText")]
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("DateTime")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("WorkTime")]
    public int WorkTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Processed")]
    public int Processed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ArrivalDateTime")]
    public DateTime ArrivalDateTime { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("RK7RefList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("RK7Reference")]
    public List<Reference> RK7RefList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("RK7Reference")]
public class Reference
{
    [XmlAttribute("RefName")]
    public string RefName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("DataVersion")]
    public int DataVersion { get; set; }
}
```